# Use actionButton() to play video inside modal dialog of a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the shiny dashboard below which includes an actionButton(). When this is pressed a modal dialog appears with another actionButton(). When I press it I want the video that can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n65kp68y9bjv7ek/Screen%20Recording%202021-05-25%20at%204.03.51%20AM.mov?dl=1) and is saved inside a subdirectory named `www` to be displayed and played inside the modal. I am also open to youtube video but it should be displayed after the button is pressed.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    
    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(titleWidth = 0
                      # Set height of dashboardHeader
                      ),
      
      dashboardSidebar(),
      dashboardBody(
        tags$div(style="display:inline-block",title="Using the range slider",actionButton("info","",icon = icon("info-circle"),style='padding:10px; font-size:80%')),
        
      )
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      observeEvent(input$info,{
        showModal(modalDialog(
          title = span(h3(strong("Distribution of cumulative reported cases (logarithmic scale)"), style = 'font-size:16px;color:#6cbabf;')),
      
          tags$div(style="display:inline-block",title="Using the range slider",actionButton("play","",icon = icon("play"),style='padding:10px; font-size:80%')),
    
          #tags$video(id="video2", type = "mov",src = "Screen Recording 2021-05-25 at 4.03.51 AM.mov", controls = "controls")
#or youtube file
        HTML('<iframe width="200" height="100" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>') )

          
        ))
        
      })
      
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
showModal(modalDialog(
  title = span(h3(strong("Distribution of cumulative reported cases (logarithmic scale)"), style = 'font-size:16px;color:#6cbabf;')),
  
  tags$div(
    style = "display:inline-block", 
    title = "Using the range slider",
    actionButton(
      "play", "", icon = icon("play"), style = 'padding:10px; font-size:80%',
      onclick = "document.getElementById('video2').play()"
    )
  ),
  tags$video(
    id = "video2", type = "mov", 
    src = "Screen Recording 2021-05-25 at 4.03.51 AM.mov", 
    controls = ""
  )
      
))
```

Comment: does it run to you? brefore pressed the button   the video be hidden